# Is possible to make a horizontal modal on flutter? Left or right

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog, flutter-layout

The question is if in flutter I can make a modal like showModalBottomSheet but from the left or the right.

If not, what is the best scope to achieve this?

Thanks!